How to force Visual Studio to regenerate files generated using Roslyn incremental generators?
How can I tell Visual Studio to regenerate files that are generated using Roslyn's incremental generator?
Context: I have a solution with a project containing custom generators and another project that uses these custom generators. Changing and building the project with custom generators does not regenerate files that were generated by the generators. How can I tell Visual Studio to force regenerate these files?
Note: Currently I have as a workaround to restart Visual Studio.
Note2: Build works OK. But IntelliSense of Visual Studio is broken. (The source code of generated files shown under Analyzers node is also outdated.) -- But unloading and reloading project that is using generators does not help.

More of a workaround, but does it help to clean your project (right click in solution explorer -> clean) before building it?

@JoshBrunton Does not seem to.

Delete the generated files manually.

@Fildor Where are the generated files? (I am using IIncrementalGenerator.)

You surely mark them like "somename.g.cs" or something like that? Then it's easiest to just serach for "*.g.cs" in your project directory (and children).

BTW: That's how I did it once. I am really in doubt if that's how you are supposed to do it. And I am following this question to see if anyone actually knows a "nice" way to force it.

@Fildor Have you used Roslyn Incremental Generators? (There are no generated files in project directory.)

I did make an "experiemental" generator for a project, where they created a lot of custom exceptions (yeah - I know...) to auto-generate public static void Throw( generated parameters) and simlar ... but I have not been able to convince them of the benefits ... so that's that.

You maybe mean T4 Text Templates that usually generate .g.cs files, not Roslyn generators?

No, I had .g.cs generated files by an incremental source generator. If I am remembering correctly, they would be shown in the IDE under the "Analyzers" node in the project tree.

@Fildor Ok. Yes, I only see these files under Analyzers node, but they are not physically present in the project folder.

Ah, right .... now that you write it ... but I am confident, I somehow deleted them explicitly to trigger re-generation. I'll have to fire up that project and try it out. I hope, it's still in my "experiements" folder ...

@Fildor Maybe stage the source files, delete them and revert the delete from stage. (But as a workaround I am currently restarting Visual Studio.)

Here are some steps you could try. 1. Clean and Rebuild the Solution
Go to Build > Clean Solution.
Go to Build > Rebuild Solution.
2. Manually Trigger a Build
Open the Build menu.
Select Build Solution or press Ctrl + Shift + B.
3. Modify Files to Trigger Rebuild
Open and make a small, non-functional change (like adding a space) to a file that references the generated code.
Save the file and trigger a build.
4. Restart Visual Studio
5. Verify Dependencies
Ensure that the project that uses the source generators has a proper reference to the project containing the source generators.


Check for Errors in Source Generators
Build the source generator project separately.
Fix any errors that appear.
Add a custom MSBuild target or script to forcefully invoke the source generators.
`





Place this target in the .csproj file of the project that uses the source generators.


@HuiLiu-MSFT

Steps 1, 2, 5, 6, 7: Build is OK, but just Visual Studio's IntelliSense is broken. (The source code of generated files shown under Analyzers node is also outdated.)
Step 3, 4 are the workarounds I am currently using.

How to reset the Visual Studio's IntelliSense "cache" for a project?

You could try the following steps to reset Visual Studio's IntelliSense cache for a project.
Close Visual Studio: Make sure Visual Studio is not running.
Click on the View tab at the top of the File Explorer window.
Click on the View tab.
Check Hidden items to show .vs folder.
Delete the .vs folder: This folder is located in the root directory of your solution. It contains various temporary data including the IntelliSense cache. Deleting this folder will reset the IntelliSense cache without affecting your source code.
Navigate to your solution directory using File Explorer.
Locate the .vs folder and delete it.
Delete the .suo file: The .suo file is also located in the solution directory and stores user-specific solution options, including IntelliSense data.
Restart Visual Studio: Open your solution again in Visual Studio. The IDE will regenerate the IntelliSense cache from scratch.

Restart of Visual Studio is enough. It is the workaround I am currently using. I want to avoid restarting Visual Studio.

PS: Having to repeatedly restart Visual Studio while developing generators is not a streamlined experience.

You could try the command dotnet build-server shutdown. For more details ,please refer here.

This command does not work with Visual Studio.

I found a free Visual Studio extension called Clear Solution IntelliSense Cache. You can install it in Visual Studio and then right-click on the solution name and click the Clear Solution IntelliSense Cache option. Hope it helps you.
